# Resolving host names to their domain name in an internal BIND domain

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, hostname, internal-dns

I'm setting up a domain on my home network for learning purposes, using BIND on CentOS to act as the name server.  I've got the name server up and running as type master for my internal domain (plumbnicoll.family), and can do forward and reverse lookups from other computers in my LAN.  For example, **host office2.plumbnicoll.family** correctly returns **office2.plumbnicoll.family has address 192.168.1.3**.

What I'd like is to be able to resolve just **office2** to its address, without needing to put .plumbnicoll.family at the end.

Is this possible, or even desirable to do?  I'm running a mixed environment at home with both Linux and Windows computers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible and perfectly desirable.  On the Linux machines:

1. Add `search plumnicoll.family` to your /etc/resolv.conf

On the Windows machines (instructions for Windows XP, other versions will require adaptation but should be similar):

1. go to Start > Settings > Network Connections
2. right-click local network connection > Properties
3. left-click Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)
4. left-click Properties
5. left-click Advanced
6. left-click DNS tab
7. left-click Append these DNS suffixes
8. left-click Add
9. type plumnicoll.family
10. left-click Add
11. left-click OK
12. left-click OK
13. left-click OK

Comment: Ah! So that is what the "search xyz" lines are for.  Doy!

Answer (score 3):

This is a client config issue, not a server config issue.  The recommendation to put the domain in the search path in resolv.conf is a client change.  You would do the same thing (albeit with a GUI) on Windows or Mac OS X, or in the DHCP scope options of your DHCP server if you're using one.

Comment: +1 for mentioning DHCP options.  I would rather make one change on the DHCP server then on each client machine, even if it is only a few on a home network.

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with your default **search domain**.  This is often pushed out by your DHCP server, or it can be set manually

(My computer | Propterties | Compuer Name | Change | **primary domain suffix**)

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your domain name as a search domain in /etc/resolv.conf, for example:

```
/etc/resolv.conf
search plumbnicoll.family
```

That should allow you to use hostnames.

Answer (score 1):

If the domain exists on the same network then place the following in your `/etc/resolv.conf`:

> domain plumbnicoll.family

You probably want to use `domain` in favour of `search` in this instance.